# count not incrementing in javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

Here i am working with a javascript code in which i am using a onclick event but somehow it is not incrementing my count value although the function is working:
The js code is:

```
var questions=[
{
    "q":"1.what is html?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"aaa"
},
{
    "q":"2.what are those?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"bbb"
},
{
    "q":"3.what is this?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"ccc"
},
{
    "q":"4.what is that?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"ddd"
}
];
var i=0;
var count=0;
show(0);
function show(i){
document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML=questions[i].q;
document.getElementById("o1").innerHTML=questions[i].a;
document.getElementById("o2").innerHTML=questions[i].b;
document.getElementById("o3").innerHTML=questions[i].c;
document.getElementById("o4").innerHTML=questions[i].d;

 }


document.getElementById("sub").onclick=function(){
if(document.getElementById("o1").checked && questions[i].a==questions[index].answer)
{
    count++;
}
 if(document.getElementById("o2").checked && questions[i].b==questions[index].answer)
{
    count++;
}
 if(document.getElementById("o3").checked && questions[i].c==questions[index].answer)
{
    count++;
}
 if(document.getElementById("o4").checked && questions[i].d==questions[index].answer)
{
    count++;
}
document.getElementById("aa").checked=false;
document.getElementById("bb").checked=false;
document.getElementById("cc").checked=false;
document.getElementById("dd").checked=false;
i++;


if(questions.length-1<i)
{   
    document.write("<body style='background-color:red;'>");
    document.write("<div>Your score is:"+count+"</div>");
    document.write("</body>")
}
show(i);
}
```

i want to know why it is not working as i don't see any error please help me.
the if block printing the count is running as background is turning red so i need to know only how to increment the count.

**the code is for the equivalent html code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Ques and Ans
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qa.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <div class="header_mid">
            <h1>BitsBridge</h1>
        </div>
    </header><br>
    <div id="main">
            <div id="ques"> 
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="aa" name="options"/>
                <span id="o1"></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="bb" name="options"/>
                <span id="o2"></span>
            </div><br>  
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="cc" name="options"/>
                <span id="o3"></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="dd" name="options"/>
                <span id="o4"></span>
            </div><br>
    </div>
 </div>
 <button type="button" class="submit" id="sub">Next</button>

 <script type="text/javascript"  src="qa.js">
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the value of `index` in `questions[index].answer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the wrong element(which is the span) by doing this `document.getElementById("o1")` 
for example, to get the first radio button you have to do it like this 
`document.getElementById("aa")`.
Second, you are using index which is not defined you have to use `i` like this
`questions[i].answer`

```js
var questions=[
{
    "q":"1.what is html?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"aaa"
},
{
    "q":"2.what are those?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"bbb"
},
{
    "q":"3.what is this?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"ccc"
},
{
    "q":"4.what is that?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"ddd"
}
];
var i=0;
var count=0;
show(0);
function show(i){
document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML=questions[i].q;
document.getElementById("o1").innerHTML=questions[i].a;
document.getElementById("o2").innerHTML=questions[i].b;
document.getElementById("o3").innerHTML=questions[i].c;
document.getElementById("o4").innerHTML=questions[i].d;

 }


document.getElementById("sub").onclick=function(){
    //console.log(questions[i].a);
    //console.log(questions[i].answer);
if(document.getElementById("aa").checked && questions[i].a==questions[i].answer)
{
    count++;
}
 if(document.getElementById("bb").checked && questions[i].b==questions[i].answer)
{
    count++;
}
 if(document.getElementById("cc").checked && questions[i].c==questions[i].answer)
{
    count++;
}
 if(document.getElementById("dd").checked && questions[i].d==questions[i].answer)
{
    count++;
}
document.getElementById("aa").checked=false;
document.getElementById("bb").checked=false;
document.getElementById("cc").checked=false;
document.getElementById("dd").checked=false;
i++;


if(questions.length-1<i)
{   
    document.write("<body style='background-color:red;'>");
    document.write("<div>Your score is:"+count+"</div>");
    document.write("</body>")
}
//console.log(count);
show(i);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Ques and Ans
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qa.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <div class="header_mid">
            <h1>BitsBridge</h1>
        </div>
    </header><br>
    <div id="main">
            <div id="ques"> 
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="aa" name="options"/>
                <span id="o1"></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="bb" name="options"/>
                <span id="o2"></span>
            </div><br>  
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="cc" name="options"/>
                <span id="o3"></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="dd" name="options"/>
                <span id="o4"></span>
            </div><br>
    </div>
 </div>
 <button type="button" class="submit" id="sub">Next</button>

 <script type="text/javascript"  src="qa.js">
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are wrong.

```
document.getElementById("o1").checked && questions[i].a==questions[index].answer
```

Firstly, there is no checked element for `document.getElementById("o1")` they are just `span`.

```
questions[i].a==questions[index].answer
```

There is no `index` definition in your code. Try to use debugger to find your mistakes.

Comment: yes sir it was a mistake corrected it.I was using it for different purpose no the query is solved.thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `i` value instead of `index` value and `document.getElementById` inside the `document.getElementById("sub").onclick` function should be `id` of the radio button instead of id of `<span>` element which you have used. Since, 
`.checked` is the property of the radio button and not a `<span>` element.

```js
var questions=[
{
    "q":"1.what is html?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"aaa"
},
{
    "q":"2.what are those?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"bbb"
},
{
    "q":"3.what is this?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"ccc"
},
{
    "q":"4.what is that?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"ddd"
}
];
var i=0;
var count=0;
show(0);
function show(i){
document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML=questions[i].q;
document.getElementById("o1").innerHTML=questions[i].a;
document.getElementById("o2").innerHTML=questions[i].b;
document.getElementById("o3").innerHTML=questions[i].c;
document.getElementById("o4").innerHTML=questions[i].d;

 }


document.getElementById("sub").onclick=function(){
if(document.getElementById("aa").checked && questions[i].a==questions[i].answer)
{
    count++;
}
 if(document.getElementById("bb").checked && questions[i].b==questions[i].answer)
{
    count++;
}
 if(document.getElementById("cc").checked && questions[i].c==questions[i].answer)
{
    count++;
}
 if(document.getElementById("dd").checked && questions[i].d==questions[i].answer)
{
    count++;
}
document.getElementById("aa").checked=false;
document.getElementById("bb").checked=false;
document.getElementById("cc").checked=false;
document.getElementById("dd").checked=false;
i++;

if(questions.length-1<i)
{   
    document.write("<body style='background-color:red;'>");
    document.write("<div>Your score is:"+count+"</div>");
    document.write("</body>")
}
show(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <div class="header_mid">
            <h1>BitsBridge</h1>
        </div>
    </header><br>
    <div id="main">
            <div id="ques"> 
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="aa" name="options"/>
                <span id="o1"></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="bb" name="options"/>
                <span id="o2"></span>
            </div><br>  
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="cc" name="options"/>
                <span id="o3"></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="dd" name="options"/>
                <span id="o4"></span>
            </div><br>
    </div>
 </div>
 <button type="button" class="submit" id="sub">Next</button>

 <script type="text/javascript"  src="qa.js">
 </script>
```